# JavaScript Events on Parent of SVG Object

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I'm currently working on a script that allows a user to embed a JavaScript file inside an SVG document to enable panning and zooming of the content.  I've tried pretty much every variation of SVG panning and zooming I could locate and have only found one that has consistent cross-browser support. Unfortunately, the script was written with the assumption that the SVG would be written out in the HTML rather than embedded through the object tag.  Since I'm working with quite a few pre-rendered SVGs, it would be more efficient to just link to an external JavaScript file in each SVG.  Everything has been going well with the conversion thus far, but I've run into a bit of a snag.  The script relies on mouse events hitting a div that wraps the SVG object.  It looks like the following:

```
<div id="svgwindow">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <object id="svg" data="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
  </div>
</div>
```

An example of the JavaScript:

```
parent.document.getElementById("svgwindow").addEventListener("mousewheel", Zoom, false);
```

This script successfully adds the event so long as the event occurs in an area of svgwindow that the svg object is not populating.  As soon as the event occurs overtop of the object the event is not captured.  I haven't been able to find any similar instances pf this to help troubleshoot the error, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `<object>` tag will capture all events and there's no way to stop it, all you can do is put another `<div>` absolutely positioned on top of the wrapper `<div>` that will receive the events.

Of course if you swap to an `<image>` tag rather than an `<object>` tag that won't capture events but there are restrictions on images e.g. all data must be in one file and no scripting allowed that may make it unsuitable for you. If it is suitable then that's easiest way to go though.

Comment: Thanks for information, I figured that there may not be an easy work around in this instance.  After some additional research, I discovered that while IE and Firefox will not pass the event to the parent div Chrome has no issues doing so.

Comment: Chrome might fix that bug one day, you never know.